# Do NSUserDefaults and SQL tables need to checked for prexistence on the phone?

Tags: ios, sql, nsuserdefaults

I have several instances in my iOS app where I utilize `NSUserDefaults` to store very basic things, like small string arrays and integer values that I would like to persist in my app. I also utilize a SQL database (via `FMDB`) to store some things locally that are larger (like a series of messages). I run into no issues on the simulator, but my question is for a live app should I be checking for existence of SQL tables or NSUserDefaults that already have the names I am trying to assign? ie is the NSUserDefaults app specific, and is the internal SQL library also app specific... is it possible for me to, by chance, create a SQL table/NSUserDefault key for my app which happens to share the same name as a table/key for another app without any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps on iOS are entirely [sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/); your app's file directories are separated from those of other apps, and the same goes for `NSUserDefaults`. You won't need to worry about overlapping.